# Rails app with docker-compose does not read .env file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a Rails app locally built with docker-compose. I'd like to keep all my config vars within `.env` and have docker-compose read from this file. However I continually run into the error when attempting this:

```
 ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres")
```

My docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data 
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file: 
      - ".env"
  web:
    container_name: puma
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    env_file:
    - ".env"            
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
volumes: 
  postgres-data:
```

When I run `docker-compose config` I can see that docker-compose is correctly reading the `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` config I've set:

```
$ docker-compose config
services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
    image: postgres
[...]
```

My `.env` lives at the root of my project directory, just like `docker-compose.yml` and looks like this (minus two other key value pairs that are redacted here):

```
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
```

Lastly, my `database.yml` file looks like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_db
  host: db
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  username: postgres
  password: ENV["POSTGRES_PASSWORD"]
```

---

Some other points in my attempts at troubleshooting this:

- I've started an interactive `byebug` session within my `web` container and can confirm that my Rails app (running in the `web`) container is returning the correct value of `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`.
- When I explicitly set my `docker-compose.yml` to include the password as seen below, the app authenticates to the DB just fine. That said, I'd really prefer to use a `.env` file, even for test and development use cases:

```
[...]
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
[...]
```

- I'm using the `dotenv` gem to load my environment variables into Rails.
- I've torn down (via docker-compose down --volumes) and rebuilt the container (`docker-compose build --no-cache) in various attempts to get this working - with no luck.

---

**tl;dr**  I feel like I've tried nearly everything to get Rails to authenticate to Postgres when using docker-compose, but just can't get it working. I'm probably missing something obvious here so I'd love another pair of

Comment: Did you try the same example without env file? If it is not connecting with Postgres, that means some issue with the code.

Comment: Don't you need to wrap your ENV["POSTGRES_PASSWORD"] with <%= ... %> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to wrap `ENV["POSTGRES_PASSWORD"]` with `<%= %>` on the `database.yml`.

**You have**

```
password: ENV["POSTGRES_PASSWORD"]
```

**You need**

```
password: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_PASSWORD"] %>
```

Comment: This was it! I can't believe I missed this.